# Flutter Sdk 31+ MISSING_PERMISSIONS when permission is granted

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, sdk

I am working on call log history app, and my application request call log history permission and phone state permission before user login. I can read call logs on lower than 31 sdk level real devices, but sdk level 31+ real devices give this error:

[image]

this is my android manifest file:

[image]

I can't found any way to fix this problem. My code is working all device lower than sdk 31.
How can I fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem like that.

Go to the app build.gradle file and change target and compile sdk versions. When some features can't work higher sdk, you should change your target sdk.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).